# Stack non-NA values to the top of each column

Tags: r, sorting, rows, na

I have a dataframe that contains values and NAs in columns. The dataframe looks like:

```
A     B     C     D
1     NA    NA    NA
NA    2     3     NA
NA    4     NA    NA
5     NA    NA    6
```

I'm trying to transform this into a form that looks like:

```
A     B     C     D
1     2     3     6
5     4     NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA
```

by stacking the non-NA values to the top in each column. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to order each column by `NA` values. Keep in mind this retains non-`NA` column order whereas `x[order(x)]` will just reorder the columns:

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))])

df1
   A  B  C  D
1  1  2  3  6
2  5  4 NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA NA
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "A     B     C     D
1     NA    NA    NA
NA    2     3     NA
NA    4     NA    NA
5     NA    NA    6")
```

Comment: Hi, is there a difference between your code and ``df1 <- data.frame(lapply(df1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]))`` (that is how I would have done it but I find your answer with df1[] interesting) ?

Comment: Hey @Gainz, I don't think there is anything different except that it should retain class and your method may coerce character to factors. If you want to read more about using `[]` with `lapply` you can check out the [Extract.data.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html) help page.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
data<- data.frame(A=c(1, NA,NA,5),
                  B=c(NA,2,4,NA),
                  C=c(NA,3,NA,NA),
                  D=c(NA,NA,NA, 6))



apply(data,2,function(x)c(x[!is.na(x)], rep(NA,(length(x)-length(x[!is.na(x)])))) )                              
      A  B  C  D
[1,]  1  2  3  6
[2,]  5  4 NA NA
[3,] NA NA NA NA
[4,] NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table` package for more flexibility -

```
> setDT(df1)

> df1[,(names(df1)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]),.SDcols=names(df1)]
```

**Note**: You can select using which columns you want to order.

```
> df1[,(c("A","B")) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]),.SDcols=c("A","B")]
```